# Uncaught SyntaxError: Export 'import_react3' is not defined in module (at chunk-...) : import_react3 as import_react,

Tags: reactjs, npm, material-ui, vite

I have created my react js application using vite. and i am using npm. I installed material ui and my package.json file has these packages:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.6",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.6",
    "@mui/material": "^5.11.15",
    "@mui/styled-engine-sc": "^5.11.11",
    "@mui/x-data-grid": "^6.0.3",
```

when i run this application, the application does not work and give me this error in console:

when i click on the "chunk" file, [this is the problematic line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydHjs.png)

That comes in the export list here:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WnC0.png).
What can i do about it?

I tried reinstalling  @emotion/styled and @emotion/react but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

remove IMPORT react3 from the component or reinstall react dependency

Answer (score 0):

One missing dependency was:
"@material-ui/core": "^4.12.4"
I installed @material-ui/core, and it worked